# Which template was used to build my VMware virtual machine?

Tags: templates, vmware

Is there any way to know which template was used to create my virtual machine? I'm in a 5.5 VMware environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It's found under the Tasks & Events tab.